# Default value of 'From:' field in TWTweetComposeViewController

Tags: ios, twitter

If a user has >1 Twitter accounts set up of their device, I would like to be able to control which account username is the default value of the From field in TWTweetComposeViewController.

At the moment it seems to default to the first Twitter account on the system and I can see no way of changing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, i't not possible to manipulate TWTweetComposeViewController more than adding an image, a link and an initial text. Apple is very clear on this:

> Although you may perform Twitter requests on behalf of the user, you
>   cannot append text, images, or URLs to tweets without the user’s
>   knowledge. Hence, you can set the initial text and other content
>   before presenting the tweet to the user but cannot change the tweet
>   after the user views it

I know that preselecting the user account it's not against it, but on the class reference I don't see a way to change the account. It's completly up to the user.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

I have a problem similar. I'm trying to fetch which account was used after the tweet. TWTweetComposeViewController seems to remember which was the last account used to tweet. If anyone knows...

Comment: Yep. Never found a way of doing it.